# Character parenting

Tags: rigging

This may be a basic question but I need help.  I've designed the character body and added the bones but I'm guessing I'm not parenting them correctly.  The bones move but the body doesn't.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project. Add images that might help us understand your scene. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-parent your bones to your body: first clear parenting by pressing Alt+P on both your 3d object and bones selected. Then in object mode select first your body object (what to parent) then bones (to what to parent) and press Ctrl+P. In drop-down menu choose "Apply armature modifier with automatic weights". This will create default and programmatically calculated bone weights to your object.
Then unselect all and pick armature, switch to Pose Mode and try to move some bones, this must take effect if you do it properly.
Also check your armature settings - it must be a "pose mode", not "rest mode" (if I remember right, it's on armature pane on your right)

After that you can correct your bones' weights by editing your mesh in "weight paint mode".
This is the very basics about rigging, since there's no much information supplied... Good luck!